# ie7 filter inheritance bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer

parent element's shadow filter give its child element's text shadow a suck visual effect. DIV's shadow effect is inherited by its child LI element. How to fix it. thanks.

```
<style>
.main_body{
display:block;
position:relative;
background:#ffc;
width:1000px;
height:1000px;
overflow:visible;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#bbbbbb', Direction=90, Strength=10);
}

.signup{
background-color: #cccccc;
display:block;
top:0;
left:0;
width:800px;
height:300px;
padding:5px 0;
}

.signup li{
list-style:none outside;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:50px;
text-align:center;
color:blue;
display:block;
zoom:1;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=3, OffY=3, Color=#99cc99,    positive=1);
}           
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main_body" align="left">
<div class="signup">
<li>blah blah</li>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `parent` & `child` `filter` are different that's why the `child` takes the `filter` of his `parent` also. So, you can write like this :

```
.main_body .signup{
 filter:0;
}
```